# React hooks how to set focus on InputGroup from a child Form.Control

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set focus on `<InputGroup>` element from his `<Form.Control>` child using `useRef` hook, in order to wrap the input and the add-on with the focus box shadow.

This is what i'm trying to achive:
[image: focus on the password field]

When i focus on the element i get an error `inputEl.current.focus is not a function`

```
<Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
<Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
<InputGroup ref={inputEl}>
  <Form.Control
    type={show ? "text" : "password"}
    placeholder="Password"
    style={{ borderRight: 0 }}
    onFocus={() => inputEl.current.focus()}
  />
  <InputGroup.Append>
    <span
      className="input-group-text"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        cursor: "pointer",
        borderLeft: 0
      }}
      onClick={() => toggle(!show)}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={show ? "eye-slash" : "eye"} />
    </span>
  </InputGroup.Append>
</InputGroup>
</Form.Group>
```

How can i access the actual DOM element from the `<InputGroup>`?

> **[The full example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-moser-ssikt)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because of this line,

```
onFocus={() => inputEl.current.focus()}
```

You are trying to focus which is not a input field.

To set style using `ref` you should do something like this,

```
<InputGroup ref={inputEl}>
   <Form.Control
       type={show ? "text" : "password"}
       placeholder="Password"
       style={{ borderRight: 0 }}
       onFocus={addStyle}
       onBlur={removeStyle}
    />
   //Rest of your code
</InputGroup>
```

```
const addStyle = () =>{
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(inputEl.current).style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)';
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(inputEl.current).style.borderRadius = '0.25rem';
}


const removeStyle = () =>{
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(inputEl.current).style.boxShadow = 'none';
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(inputEl.current).style.borderRadius = '0';
}
```

Comment: I want the focus to be set to the parent element of the form control. So it will wrap the whole element.

Comment: What you want to achieve while focusing on wrapper of input?

Comment: To get the bootstrap border shadow to wrap the input group on focus and not only the input element

Comment: Have you checked the updated answer? Is it working?